# A complete formalization of EGA in Lean

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, proof-assistants, formalization

I have been lately thinking about the feasibility of creating a "mediocre algebraic geometer" AI. I thought that to train it, one could feed it some large chunks of algebraic geometry presented in an accessible form.

I do not think that human-written text counts as an accessible form, even one using very limited number of words so it would be less headache if it was written in a formal logic language (I think Lean has sufficient functionality for this, for example).

Has EGA been translated into Lean or any other language aimed at formalizing mathematics? Given that EGA was written pretty transparently (and there were very few errors for a text of this length, two or three maybe), it should not be excessively hard to do this but it can require quite some time to translate all the volumes.

Comment: How do you know that there are only two or three mistakes in the whole EGA's?

Comment: @Libli well, I do not know for sure (I did say "maybe", hehe cunning me). I think there was one about formal smoothness, there was another one too which I can not remember. That should give a lower bound. Giving an upper bound depends on what sort of argument you are looking for (community consensus or something else).

Comment: Do you think someone read all the EGA's line by line?

Comment: @Libli does someone have to?

Comment: Well, what I wanted to say, is that I am not even sure that there is a group of scientists who has ever had the time and courage to read all the EGA line by line to check that validity of all statements. So, at least to me, it seems an impossible task for a group of scientists to formalize the EGA's in Lean.

Comment: @Libli I see your concern, thank you. I am by no means an expert in Lean but I think that if your proof is not complete it won't compile so it is impossible to fool yourself (that does not mean that you will be able to find a correct proof, of course). However, if you are aware of a formalization of Zariski's main theorem, for example, that would be of interest too.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard maybe you can comment on this.

Comment: I think it's fitting and proper to invite Kevin Buzzard to this question.

Comment: @FanZheng I am not sure what is the point of your comment. Did someone claim it is not fitting and proper to invite Kevin Buzzard to this question?

Comment: @Libli. Yes, I think that many students of the École Normale Supérieure have read all of EGA line by line: it has been some sort of challenge at that school for nearly 60 years and I guess that a couple of students each year manage to do just that. And mathematicians from other countries too:  Deligne, Gabber, Suslin, Faltings, etc... Also, I don't see why it should take "courage" to read such a beautifully written, crystal clear , profound and epoch making treatise.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg you mean they read all of the volumes within one year, or just that on average there are 3 students finishing it any given year? In any case, my admiration to them.

Comment: Dear @Asura: let's say (to be on the safe side) that they finish reading all the volumes in a given year. On the other hand people like Deligne, Faltings and Gabber are rumored to have read EGA in about 6 months. I have heard that [Jean-Charles Naouri](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Charles_Naouri#Formation) quickly read all of EGA after being admitted to the ÉNS  at the top of his cohort. He wrote his Ph.D. in one year  but then (through lack of ambition ?) quit mathematics. He settled for a career as a businessman and his fortune is estimated at 0.5 billion euros. Sad story, eh?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I see. I myself was in a position to read it for over two years now (in the sense that most definitions were within reach), have tried a few times, but failed. On the other hand I am slightly confused about Deligne, I think he had some contributions to EGA too (e.g. the finite presentation assumptions in Zariski's main theorem) so it was not really a finished project when he came to the scene.

Comment: Dear @Asura, Deligne came to the ÉNS (with special permission, since he is not French but Belgian) in 1965 and that's about when he started reading EGA. The last part of EGA (Volume IV, 4) was published in 1967, so written in 1966 at the latest. This seems to imply that Deligne  read all of EGA **and  co-wrote the last part** in about a year, which is even much more remarkable! (I knew that he co-organized the SGA seminars with Grothendieck but I didn't know that he had already contributed to EGA.  Interesting information, but  absolutely not surprising!)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I just looked it up to check myself for truthfulness, the reference is EGA IV, quatrieme partie, Section 18.12: "Les résultats de ce numéro nous ont été communiqués par P. Deligne."

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting: thank you, Asura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schemes have been formalized in Lean, with the aim of verifying formally some parts of the Stacks project: see [here](https://github.com/kbuzzard/lean-stacks-project) and [here](https://github.com/ramonfmir/lean-scheme). They have schemes but I'm not sure they have morphisms of schemes yet. This should give you a feeling of the difficulty of the task.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear whether which of the following you're most interested in:

1. Formalizing EGA specifically.
2. Formalizing in Lean specifically.
3. Teaching an AI to do mathematics by giving it a bunch of formalized mathematics and waving a magic wand while muttering the magic spell "deep learning."

Questions 1 and 2 are relatively easy to answer.  Nobody has formalized EGA in Lean or any other proof assistant.  I think you overestimate how easy it is to formalize significant amounts of mathematics using a proof assistant.  I recommend that you look through the slides of a talk by Neil Strickland, [Proof assistants as a routine tool?](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/talks/pa_talk.pdf) to get a sense of where the state of the art is.  (Strickland's slides were written a while ago but the current situation is still mostly as he described it.)  Until it gets a *lot* easier to use proof assistants, formalizing EGA is unlikely to happen.

As for Question 3, the idea has long been at the back of the minds of many people who work with formal proofs.  While I think the time is not yet ripe for such a project, there's no harm in trying.  But if you do want to try, and if you don't have your heart set on algebraic geometry per se, it probably makes sense to pick some area of mathematics that has already been formalized to a significant extent, rather than start from scratch.  For example you could try to join the univalent foundations / homotopy type theory community.

Comment: if the first paragraph was intended as a criticism of the question, I do not agree with it (there was only one sentence with a question mark, namely "Has EGA been translated into Lean or any other language aimed at formalizing mathematics? ", so I guess in your trichotomy that is 1).

Comment: +1: a helpful answer, I appreciate the remark about the difficulty of formalizing EGA, I did not know that.

Comment: The situation has improved in a number of ways since I wrote those slides.  If you want to use Coq, there is now a single installer that will give you Coq + ssreflect + the mathematical components library, and the book (https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/) by Mahboubi and Tassi is much better than previously available documentation.  Lean also has more involvement of active mathematicians, and I think that the ecosystem works better than for other systems.  It would be a lot of work to formalise EGA, but I would say that we know how to do it.

Comment: @NeilStrickland It would be, I think, helpful to have a ballpark estimate for how much work would be involved to formalise EGA with presently available tools. Are we talking 1 person-month or 100 person-years?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler my guess would be 10 person-years.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the Lean Forward project (https://lean-forward.github.io/).  This is in number theory rather than algebraic geometry, but it is probably the largest and most well organised current project aiming to apply formalisation to current research.

For applications of AI to this area, here are two abstracts from the Big Proof 2019 meeting in Edinburgh:

> Saxton, David (DeepMind)
>
> Teaching machines to do mathematics like humans
>
> Can we teach machines
>   to do mathematics following the same curriculum that we use for
>   humans? We released a dataset of synthetic school level mathematical
>   questions - what happens when we try to train standard
>   state-of-the-art learning models (without any prior mathematical
>   knowledge) to answer these? (Spoiler: they can do well on many but not
>   all problem types - and their perceptual reasoning process is still a
>   long way off from the power of humans.) We also look at motivations
>   for doing this, and speculate on what next steps might be for learning
>   models that could do harder mathematics (perhaps eventually things
>   like conjectures and proofs) in a human-like fashion.

.

> Urban, Josef (Prague)
>
> Learning and Reasoning over Big Proof Corpora
>
> The talk
>   will give a brief overview of recent methods that combine learning and
>   reasoning over large formal libraries. I will mention the "hammer"
>   linkups between ITPs and ATPs, systems that learn and perform direct
>   tactical guidance of ITPs, discuss learning of premise selection over
>   large libraries and learning-based guidance of saturation-style and
>   tableaustyle automated theorem provers (ATPs) trained over the large
>   proof corpora. I will also mention feedback loops between proving and
>   learning in this setting, and show our auto formalization experiments.

Comment: indeed, very interesting stuff. Unfortunately, I never received formal instruction in CS or AI so it will take me some time to learn all of the fancy terms.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already tried this: as a source for "large chunks of algebraic geometry" they used the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/). You can read more about the results here:

Chojecki, P. (2017), *[DeepAlgebra - An Outline of a Program](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-62075-6_1)*. In: Geuvers H., England M., Hasan O., Rabe F., Teschke O. (eds), *Intelligent Computer Mathematics - CICM 2017*, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 10383, Springer.

(EDIT, in response to comments: The emphasis here is on *tried*. I did not claim that this programme had already succeeded in creating a formalization of any substantial chunk of algebraic geometry. The programme proposed by Chojecki also differs from the context of the question in that -- if I understand correctly -- Chojecki proposes to train an AI directly on the natural-language text of the Stacks Project, while the questioner proposes to have humans rewrite EGA in a formal language and then use that to train an AI.)

Comment: it appears they are even going further: "We outline a program in the area of formalization of mathematics to automate theorem proving in algebra and algebraic geometry." They automate something we are struggling to do by hand in a single case!

Comment: it also appears that we are using the phrase "large chunks of algebraic geometry presented in an accessible form" in different ways (Stacks project definitely not match my usage of this phrase). So I am not sure whom you are quoting.

Comment: Why not? "The Stacks project is an ever growing open source textbook and reference work on algebraic stacks and the algebraic geometry needed to define them. [...] he aim is to build algebraic geometry and use this in laying the foundations for algebraic stacks. The theory of commutative algebra, schemes, varieties, and algebraic spaces forms an integral part of the Stacks project." They're really starting from the ground up; I refer you to e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/006S (the definition of a sheaf on a topological space).

Comment: Well, when I said accessible I meant accesible to computers (as can be inferred from the second paragraph of the question). I do not think that right know computers know how to read so Stacks project is going to be problematic in this regard. It is pretty accessible to first-year grad students, on the other hand, so in that sense I agree.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Last time I checked, they haven’t made meaningful progress after writing this very bold “outline of a program”.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger just out of curiosity, Dr. Achinger, I think you are an arithmetic geometer with some interests outside of that area. Have you been following the recent advances in machine learning, automation and formal theorem proving closely? I find it very hard to imagine somebody could come across this paper when not thinking specifically about the question in the OP.

Comment: @AsuraPath not really, no.

Comment: I follow the advances in machine learning and formal theorem proving, and I think there is no chance of this project succeeding unless somebody invested literally a billion dollars in it.